# drop down menu not opening consistently with respect to button

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu whose horizontal location depends on the width of the browser's window, and O can't find the way to get it open under the button with the left border aligned to the left border of the button.

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="navbar-brand navbar-left" style="width:48%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;margin: 8px 0 0 0">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> <label>{{Current_Language_Record.Code}}</label>
        </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:10px;left:0;width:250px" role="menu">
          <li href="#" 
              ng-repeat="One_Entry in Interface_Languages_List | IF_Lang_Filter: Current_Language_Record.Code track by $index" 
              ng-click="New_Set_Language(One_Entry);" 
              style="cursor:pointer">
              {{One_Entry.Code}} - {{One_Entry.NativeName}}
              <hr ng-if="!$last">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

I tried adding the classes `dropdown-menu-right` and `dropdown-menu-left` but they don't show to have any effect. Also tried `pull-right` (which did the trick with another button I have) with no effect either.

Could anyone suggest what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have an online demo?

Comment: Nope. The posted code is exactly the source (as you can see, the project includes AngularJS).

Comment: Hello @MojtabaSabeti, do you see any **obvious** error in my code that might be the source of the problem I'm experiencing?